# How do I test a predicate against a seq of args?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure

I've generated a seq of arg lists, e.g.:

`[[a b c]
  [d e f]
  [g h i]]`

... such that `(map (partial apply f) that-seq)` should produce a list of the same result. I want to check if all of these indeed produce that same result. Normally, you'd use the `are` macro for something like this, but I don't have a literal bunch of exprs to test against: I have a seq. So, I guess I want the "equivalent" of (apply are ...). As far as I can tell, my options are:

- write a macro
- Use `every? true?`, giving up on useful error messages.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for more accurate reporting

```
(testing "blake2b defaults are accurate"
  (doseq [args-variation blake2b-empty-args-variations]
    (is (= (seq empty-string-digest)
           (seq (blake2b args-variation)))
        (str "Args variation: " (seq args-variation)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, for now, I've gone with:

```
(testing "blake2b defaults are accurate"
  (let [results (map #(apply blake2b %) blake2b-empty-args-variations)]
    (is (every? (partial array-eq empty-string-digest) results))))
```

Comment: Can't reason about this code without knowing what the symbols mean. If it is supposed to illustrate your question you should post it as part of the question.

Comment: Nope, it's a resolution, hence an answer. `blake2b-empty-args-variations` is the seq of arg lists; so, I am mapping that `#(apply blake2b %)` over that arg list (expecting all the same results, as mentioned in the original question). Then, I'm checking that each of those is the result I expected. Since the expected return value is a `byte[]`, I have to use array-eq (really just `java.util.Arrays.equals`) instead of plain old `=`, which does identity on arrays.

Code here: https://github.com/lvh/caesium/blob/7377830ed7a91f3a99e563ee02442c343604b4d8/test/caesium/crypto/generichash_test.clj#L31